# ScriptException converting json to map Java 8 Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

As with the recent Java update 8u60 java has supported json to map converstion using Nashorn Script Engine, I have been trying to checkout same using the sample code provided [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Java.asJSONCompatible). However, its giving me [ScriptException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html) with the below stacktrace. I'm using Java 8u65 to run the given code.

Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError:
>   Cannot call undefined in  at line number 1  at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:455)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:439)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:401)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:397)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:152)
>     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>     at JSONTest.main(JSONTest.java:8) Caused by: :1 TypeError:
>   Cannot call undefined     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)

Answer (score 0):

Will you please check your JDK version? It should print something like:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I compiled and run JSONTest.java from Nashorn wiki page with both JDK 8u60 and 8u65. It worked as expected:

```
$ java JSONTest
343
2
4
5
```

I tested on Windows 7, 64 bit version with Cygwin shell (but that should not produce any difference in behavior)

Answer (score -1):

Ensure the jar file containing the jdk is in your classpath

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, what do you mean by "Jar file containing jdk". Don't you think all it needs is the runtime environment.

Comment: The jdk libs are packaged into jar files.  You need to include each one that you use in your classpath.  For me in CentOS the nashorn.jar file is here /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar